Which platform/server should I use to deploy my nodejs + redis backend code?
I built a mobile app using react native with firestore.
And for the backend code, I used node.js to build it with redis.
From my local they are running great so now all the codes are completed, I need to deploy it.
For frontend side, I know I just need to post it on the app/play store but for the backend code, I'm not sure where to deploy.
I would want it to run same as how run it in the local. (Just simple npm run server)
I tried firebase functions/hosting but I cannot see any logs and not sure if my .env file is there or not and if it is running.
Which platform should I use so I can use redis and node.js as it is without modifying my current code?
